# Delete actions of this tutorial not are not working because I'm using Rails 3.1 which uses jQuery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following this tutorial"

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

The tutorial seems to be using Rails 3.0. I am using Rails 3.1.

I get the following errors each time I try to delete a micropost:

> No route matches [GET] "/microposts/301"

and deleting a user takes me to the user's page instead:

> http://localhost:3000/users/6

I heard Rails 3.1 uses jQuery instead of Prototype.js.

Do I have to create o download any files in order to get the deleting action working?
(in which files do I have to place them and how do I call/include them?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an entire [chapter](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-3-1#top) about rails 3.1 in that tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the code (at least the view) ? Right now, I'd say that while the route is fine, the method should be `DELETE`, not `GET`. Do you pass `:method => :delete` to `link_to` ?

Comment: The code is exactly as chapter 11 of the tutorial I mention above (sorry I'm typing this from a public toilet).